# Delete file from the project folder no matter where the project is located

Tags: asp.net

The code below won't find the file in the folder. I tried different spellings (with ~, without @, forward slash), but to no avail. In debugger mode VS shows me that the Environment.CurrentDirectory is "bla-bla\IIS".

```
    string fileName = @"\UploadedFiles\CONF 23 2020-04-03T21-26-36.pdf";
    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Delete(path);
    }
```

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDirectory` may be of use to you. And if this is a console app, this may give you the project/bin/debug folder. So you could do something like `@"..\..\..\UploadedFiles\"` to access further out folders. Please provide your project folder path and UploadedFiles folder path.

Comment: What use in providing the path like "C:\....". If I run the project from another folder, then I will have to change everything? I want to make the code sustainable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "DirectoryInfo". For Example:

```c
var directory = new DirectoryInfo($"{Server.MapPath(@"\")}FileUploads");    
var filePath = Path.Combine(directory.ToString(),fileName);    
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
   File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fateme Mirjalili.
The code that works for me is:

```
 var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/UploadedFiles") 
                + "\\" + "\test.pdf";

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {

            }
```